# Automatically send invites to guests in a new calendar event, and the email is a variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a google calendar event and to sent invites. 
only problem - my guests are listed as a variable.
the code actually works when i specify the email , but it doesn't when   i use a variable. 
please help me to understand what am i doing wrong..

```
 var event= calendar.createEvent(name+' '+'Birthday', new Date(JSdate), new Date(JSdate),{"Description" : "Birthday" , "Location" : "Home" , "Guests" : contact , "SendInvites":"true"})
```

in my code name is a variable, and contact is the email variable, both are values from google sheets.